# GTK4 ScrolledWindow renders content unreadable

Tags: python, gtk, gtk4, scrolledwindow, gtkscrolledwindow

I am learning GTK4 and Python. While playing round with the `Gtk.StackSidebar` class, I came across this strange behavior that I cannot seem to figure out.

I want my sidebar on the left, and my content to be scrollable. To do this I introduced a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow` container between the content (grid) and the stack. When I do this, the content of the grid is no longer readable, as it has been cut down in size. However, the small content is scrollable now.

Here is what it looks like:[image]

I would like to understand why, when the grid is wrapped in a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow` its contents is shrinked, leaving extra unwanted space for the stack sidebar.

My code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
gi.require_version('Adw', '1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Adw


class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.set_title("Demo")
        self.set_default_size(400, 400)

        #
        # Create grid and add some content to be scrolled
        #

        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()

        for row in range(50):
            self.grid.attach(Gtk.Label(label = "Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text"), 0, row, 1, 1)
 
        #
        # Wrap grid in ScrolledWindow
        #

        self.scrollableContent = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrollableContent.set_child(self.grid)

        #
        # Create a stack, Add the ScrolledWindow.
        #

        self.content = Gtk.Stack()
        self.content.add_titled(self.scrollableContent, "Scrollable", "Content . . . . . . . . ")

        #
        # Create the sidebar and add the stack.
        #

        self.sidebar = Gtk.StackSidebar()
        self.sidebar.set_stack(self.content)

        #
        # Create a box to hold the sidebar and the content stack side by side Horizontaly.
        #

        self.structure = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)

        self.structure.set_homogeneous(False) # just to be sure

        self.structure.append(self.sidebar)      
        self.structure.append(self.content)

        #
        # Set the box as the content of the window it self.
        #

        self.set_child(self.structure)




class DemoApp(Adw.Application):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.connect('activate', self.on_activate)


    def on_activate(self, app):
        self.win = MainWindow(application=app)
        self.win.present()

app = DemoApp(application_id="com.vildljung.Demo")
app.run(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I can reproduce with Gtkmm 3.24.

Comment: Are you looking for a technical solution or only to understand what is happening?

Comment: I would like to understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that by default, the `GtkScrolledWindow` does not take into account the child widget's dimensions when computing its own.

In your case, it seems the height was computed accordingly, but not the width. The API proposes [this function](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.ScrolledWindow.set_propagate_natural_width.html):

```c
void
gtk_scrolled_window_set_propagate_natural_width (
  GtkScrolledWindow* scrolled_window,
  gboolean propagate
)
```

which makes sure the child's widget's dimensions are propagated to the scrolled window dimensions.

I tried it on Gtkmm3.24 and it solved the issue.

Source : https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/3515

Comment: self.scrollableContent.set_propagate_natural_width(True)

Problem solved. Thank you!